# Facebook login without SSL

Tags: facebook, ssl, authentication

This is not another question asking if I need to buy an SSL cert for my site to have a facebook login.

My question is, is it possible, when using facebook's login with OAuth2, to NOT redirect the user to https:// www. facebook.com?

My problem is this, I run a bunch of wireless hotspots and would like the users to login via facebook. The problem is that I need to give them access to https ://www. facebook.com/login.php ( and a bunch of other urls). however with HTTPS I cannot allow access to paths on websites if its an SSL site. So is the another domain name that can be used (like HTTPS :// login.facebook.com*) or a way to send them to HTTP ://www. facebook.com/login?

EDIT:

Just to make it more clear what I am trying to do.

Open your browser and go to http://www.facebook.com/login, facebook will then redirect you to HTTPS:// www. facebook.com/login. That is the problem. Is there anyway, using the php sdk to force HTTP & not HTTPS

Comment: share some code and help is a lot easier. My guess is the callback is faulty..

Answer (score 1):

You only need SSL for **Canvas Apps** (running on apps.facebook.com/yournamespace, "App on Facebook" in the developer settings) and **Page Apps** ("Page Tab" in the developer settings), but not for external Websites.

Just fill in the input field "**Website with Facebook Login**" in the developer settings with your external Website (http://www.yourdomain.com/whatever).

Where you redirect the user to is totally up to you. For example, you can create any JavaScript redirection in the callback function of FB.login:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/